# Redshift serverless database RPU

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm currently using Redshift serverless and aiming to track the Resource Provisioning Units (RPUs) consumed by individual databases within the system. Redshift conveniently provides the sys_serverless_usage system view, offering this information at a workgroup level. However, I'm seeking a method to accurately calculate or estimate the RPU usage for a specific database.

Any insights or alternative approaches for accurately calculating database-specific RPU usage would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I attempted to utilize the SYS_QUERY_HISTORY view, which contains database identifiers. However, when I tried to sum the elapsed_time from SYS_QUERY_HISTORY and the compute_seconds from sys_serverless_usage for the same minute, I encountered discrepancies. I had expected these values to be at least closely aligned.